# Ability to print a message in R console to indicate function is successful?

Tags: r

say I have a simple function that I want to run in R. If the function runs successfully, I would like the R console to print a message similar to "Function Ran Successfully" and if it doesn't, R uses its normal error or warning messages to explain what is wrong with the function. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `message("hello world")`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is message() a better choice than print() in R for writing a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699272/why-is-message-a-better-choice-than-print-in-r-for-writing-a-package)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `message` or `cat` or `print`.  If you use `message`, someone else has the option of invoking your function wrapped with `suppressMessages()`.  `cat` is going to print to the terminal no matter what.  Also, you have to end `cat` with a `\n` if you want the CRLF.

Messages are printed in red.

```
message("Function Ran Successfully")
cat("Function Ran Successfully\n")
```

If you want colored messages, use the `crayon` package

```
cat(crayon::green$bold("Function Ran Successfully\n"))
```

`print` is particularly useful if you want to print out a structure, rather than just a single string.

```
print(head(iris, 2))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

Comment: If the function fails, will it print the standard R error message or will I need to specify a message for the function failing with this? All I am looking to do is create a success message but not change anything about what R would put if it is wrong.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 'fail'.  If it fails by, say, dividing by 0, or taking the square root of a character string - yes, you'll get an error message of some flavor.  If it fails by returning an empty data frame, (that you didn't want) you'll need to specify the message.  I like to put my success messages in green.

Comment: `crayon` is delivered as standard even with minimal install right? otherwise people without the package would get an error

Comment: @jimmymcheung - Yes, it's in the minimal install.  I believe it's used for the red printing in `warning`

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <- function(num) {
  #code here

  num = as.integer(readline(prompt="Enter a number: "))

  if (num>0){ print("positive number")}
  else if (num<0){ print("negative number")}
  else { print("zero")}
}  
fun()
```

Run `fun()` and input a value in the console.

This is a example with nasted loop, maybe that is what you want if you are creating your own funtions (besides this word in other cases to), if not let me know and I will delete this answer.